# Block and Pulley Problem with Friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image: HW Problem]

**1.) What is the acceleration of the hanging mass? (Indicate the direction with the sign of your answer.)**

**2.) Determine the tension in the cord. (Indicate the direction with the sign of your answer.)**

Seems like the simplest problem but I cant seem to get the right answer. Here's my approach:

---

$n $ = normal force on $m_1 $

$f_s $ = friction force on $m_1 $

$T $ = tension in the cord

$\mu_k $ = coefficient of kinetic friction

---

**Problem 1.)**

$(1)\quad n = m_1 g = (40kg)(9.8m/s^2)$

$(2)\quad n = 392 N$

$(3)\quad f_s = \mu_k n = (0.22)(392N)$

$(4)\quad f_s = 86.24N$

$(5)\quad T = m_2 g - f_s$

$(6)\quad T = (13.4kg)(9.8m/s^2) - 86.24N$

$(7)\quad T = 131.32N - 86.24N = 45.08N$

$(8)\quad m_2 a_{m_2} = m_2 g - T$

$(9)\quad (13.4kg) a_{m_2} = 131.32N - 45.08N$

$(10)\quad (13.4kg) a_{m_2} = 86.24N$

$(11)\quad a_{m_2} = 86.24N/13.4kg = 6.44m/s^2$

$6.44m/s^2$ is wrong, though. Could someone point me in the right direction? Any feedback is welcome, and thanks in advance

**SOLUTION:**

Equation (5) should be $T-f_s = m_1 a$

$T-f_s = m_1 a$

becomes (after rearranging)

$T-(40kg)a = 86.24N$

and

$m_2 a = m_2 g - T$

becomes (after rearranging)

$T + (13.4kg)a = 131.32N$.

Then we throw those two equations into a matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -40 & 86.24 \\
1 & 13.4 & 131.32
\end{bmatrix}

Solve, and our answers will be:

$a = 0.84m/s^2$

$T = 120.01N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the 5 equation is completely wrong. 
It should be T-fs=m1a.
Also acceleration of m1 = acceleration of m2 since rope is inextesible

Comment: @user49147 You can see that friction is not acting on m1 but on m2

Comment: In equation (5) I changed $m_1 $ to $m_2 $ and carried out the rest of the problem with the same equations, and ended up with $-13.02m/s^2 $, which is still incorrect. Is there anything else with my work I should change?

Comment: Ok the 5 equation is completely wrong. It should be T-fs=m1a. Also acceleration of m1 = acceleration of m2 since rope is inextesible @user49147

Comment: Okay, I messed around with that equation for a bit, but keep running into problems. How would you find T? Because otherwise, there are two unknown variables in that equation

Comment: You have 2 variables T and a and 2 equations 5 and 8.It would be better to chat in chat room rather than increasing comments here. If you want .Also after getting your answer please accept my solution.

Comment: then we can proceed discussion here only and delete your previous comments which were not related to question @user49147

Comment: Got it! Two equations, two variables.